# Android Preference with long summary (explanation)

Tags: android, android-preferences, summary

I have a preference that represents some complex notion.
I'd like to explain it, and the explanation is a bit long.
When I add the explanation to the summary of the preference it gets cut off.
Is there a standard for Android having long summary/description/explanation?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any standard for long settings explanations.

### My solution

I set the summary to be the value chosen by the preference and added a dialog with a long message to explain the chosen setting when it is chosen.

This kind of keeps the settings UI standard without the need to custom the standard preference layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own preference widget: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:widgetLayout

Comment: So no standard? Need to custom my preference?

Comment: TextView has a maxLength property defaulting at unlimited. This must be set to a smaller value for default preference widget, to maintain a uniform look and feel.

Comment: What you wrote is the reason that long summary is cut off, Which is good. I'm asking about a standard way to still add it. It's not a must to be in the summary section.

Answer (score 0):

[Material design says that you should make the preference open a separate screen that includes the description](https://material.google.com/patterns/settings.html#settings-grouping-settings):

> Settings that require longer explanations may add a description on a second screen.
>
> [image]
>
> Underneath the label, show the status text of the switch as "On" or "Off.”
>
> [image]
>
> Add the switch itself and a longer description to a second screen.

For an example of this, go to Settings -> Accessibility -> Magnification Gestures.